# ASP.NET MVC - Status Codes without HTML

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express, http-status-codes

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 project on my local machine using IIS Express using Visual Studio 2010. I have a controller that returns HTTP status codes via `HttpStatusCodeResult`. I am noticing that IIS Express is returning HTML along with my status code.

I don't want to be lugging around all this extra HTML. Plain HTTP headers is all my JavaScript cares about. Is this something I can shut off in the web.config or is this specific to IIS Express?

I am also curious whether there will be any interaction between my status codes and the `customErrors` section. If I return a `404`, will it redirect to my 404 page? From my tests, it doesn't appear to be an issue, but I want to make sure.

Comment: I would think you could set something IIS to turn that off.  This page looks like it might have the details to achieve what you want: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors

Comment: if you host under iis 7, then by default detailed error messages are turned off, so a bare bones message is returned to the client.